# Hibernate not updating status of entity after save

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, transactions

In our spring boot application, we are encountering a problem with basic saving of an entity after modifying it. Even though the log right before the save operation is printed (GCP logging), the ticket entity is not modified (status is still 'invalid').

### The code

```
@EventListener
@Async
public void handleStripeWebhook(StripeWebhookEvent stripeWebhookEvent) throws EntityNotFoundException, StripeException {
    final var event = stripeWebhookEvent.event();
    final var stripeObject = stripeWebhookEvent.stripeObject();

    Invoice invoice;
    Subscription subscription;
    switch (event.getType()) {
        case "invoice.paid":
            // get invoice
            invoice = (Invoice) stripeObject;
            if (invoice.getSubscription() != null) {
                subscriptionService.onInvoicePaid(invoice);
            }
            break;
        // ...
        // omitted code
        // ...
    }
}

@Transactional
public void onInvoicePaid(Invoice invoice) throws EntityNotFoundException {
   // ...
   // omitted code
   // ...
   final var tickets = issueCurrentMonthTicketAfterInvoicePaid(mySubscription);
   // ...
   // omitted code
   // ...
}


private List<TicketEntity> issueCurrentMonthTicketAfterInvoicePaid(SubscriptionEntity mySubscription) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    // ...
    // omitted code
    // ...
    List<TicketEntity> tickets = ticketRepository.findAllBySubscriptionIdAndValidFromGreaterThanEqual(mySubscription.getId(), mySubscription.getLastIssuedPeriodStart());
    for (TicketEntity ticket : tickets) {
       if (ticket.getStatus() == TicketTypeEnum.INVALID) {
          ticket.setStatus(TicketTypeEnum.VALID);
          ticketRepository.save(ticket);
          log.info("Invoice paid for subscription-id: " + moplaSubscription.getId() + " (" + mySubscription.getStripeSubscriptionId() + ") -> setting ticket " + ticket.getId() + " to valid.");
       }
    }
}
```

### Ticket entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TICKETS")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE TICKETS SET deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
public class TicketEntity {

    // ...
    // omitted code
    // ...

    /**
     * The status of the ticket.
     */
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    @Convert(converter = TicketTypeConverter.class)
    private TicketTypeEnum status;

    // ...
    // omitted code
    // ...
}
```

### Logs

After running this code, the ticket is still invalid even though in the log, we see this:

```
2024-02-03T02:44:25.479Z  INFO 1 --- [     task-17886] d.m.s.core.services.SubscriptionService  : Invoice paid for subscription-id: xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx (sub_xxxxxxxxxxxxx) -> setting ticket yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy to valid.
```

### Database

In the database, we can see that the `updated_time` is set correctly (but the status is not updated to 'VALID'):
[image]

### Ideas

After the save operation the method ends. We do not see any errors in the logs, so I do not think it is a rollback. Could this somehow be connected to a transactional context being executed inside an async event listener?

Comment: It is never persisted. To persist data you need a transaction, I see no `@Transactional` anywhere. No transaction no persistence. As Hibernate is write-behind it will only write when told so, a save is not the way to tell it that.

Comment: There is a `@Transactional` on `onInvoicePaid` in which `issueCurrentMonthTicketAfterInvoicePaid` is called. Does that not count?

Comment: My bad, just re-read your question, are you updating the status actually? As times are being updated. What does your `Ticket` entity look like, where does it come from (it magically appears it seems).

Comment: I added more code to explain where the ticket entity is coming from and also the relevant parts of the ticket entity itself. As you can see `ticket.setStatus(TicketTypeEnum.VALID);` is called right before calling the save operation.

Comment: Is your converter messing things up? Is there a reason for not use `@Enumerated` instead? There is an `@Where` does that impact things here?

Comment: The enumerator is legacy-code that is being used in a lot of instances without issues.

The @Where clause (used for soft-delete)  is not relevant since this object has deleted=false.

Comment: IMHO that is legacy code that can be removed as enumeration support has been added a long time ago. I still doubt the `@Transactional` is doing anything or that the classes portrait here are used as is (it isn't an internal call but really a call into an external service?). I also wonder if there are any relations between your entities which interfere with each other. You should also make sure you have a proper `hashCode` and `equals` method on your entities.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "it isn't an internal call but really a call into an external service?". The classes depicted here are the ones being executed as the logs show.